# UIImageView Tint Color weirdness

Tags: uiimageview, tintcolor

I'm using pdf images in Xcode 10.
The settings are as follows:

[image: PDF Image settings]

As you can see the image has been set to be rendered as `Template Image`

Now when setting the image in an imageView and setting the tint color, this weird thing happens:

1. If the tint color is not white or any white hue, **it is rendered correctly** on the phone
2. If the tint color is set to white or any hue that is white (light gray, etc), then it's rendered fine in the Interface Builder, but **it appears black** on the phone

I even tried setting the tint color at runtime, but same thing happens.
Any clues why this is happening?

I'm starting to think this is a bug in Xcode, but wondering if I missed something!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems to be indeed a bug.
Found this:

http://openradar.appspot.com/23759908

And yes, calling `tintColorDidChange` in `viewWillAppear` does solve the problem.